# Why can't I map a group of indices into a set of enum types?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Future<Settings> getSettings() async {
final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final username = preferences.getString("username");
final isEmployed = preferences.getBool("isEmployed");
final gender = Gender.values[preferences.getInt("gender") ?? 0];

final programmingLanguageIndices =
    preferences.getStringList("programmingLanguages");
    
  final programmingLanguages = programmingLanguageIndices
      .map((strIndex) => ProgrammingLanguage.values[int.parse(strIndex)])
      .toSet();


return Settings(
    username ?? "", gender, programmingLanguages, isEmployed ?? false);
}
```

Here is the error: `The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'`

So I tried adding some null checks but nothing has worked so far...

[image: Dart code snippet]

Comment: `programmingLanguageIndices!.map` because it can receive null value from `SharedPreferences`. maybe it will solve the error.

Comment: The error specifically complains about the call to `programmingLanguageIndices.map`, so you must check that `programmingLanguageIndices` is not `null` before calling `.map`.  You can use an explicit `null` check (`if (programmingLanguageIndices != null) { ... }`), use a null-aware operator (`programmingLanguageIndices?.map(...)`), or assert that it can never be `null` in practice (`programmingLanguageIndices!.map(...)`).